# Error show code use plugin Code Snippet of CKEditor in view page Laravel

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

I'm using plugin Code Snippet of CKEditor:

[image]

I saved it in the database, but when I show it in view page it's showing an error like this:

[image]

So, can you help me!

p/s: i use Laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display unescaped data using the format below:

```
{!! $unescaped !!}
```

Read more: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade

Comment: I am trying to install code snippet in VueJS Laravel project. But not getting results. Do you have any resource link from where I can get step by step guide. Thanks in advance.